# A question about Nakayama's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, modules

I am studying the following lemma given by Huneke in his algebra notes - II.
[image]

I have the following question: how does Nakayama's Lemna give us the polynomial $g$?

Comment: Nakayama's Lemma does not directly give you this polynomial $g$. Rather, it gives you a polynomial $s \equiv 1 \bmod{(t)}$ such that $sM = 0$. Write out the definition of this equivalence, and you will find your $g$.

Comment: A proof that doesn't mention Nakayama's lemma is the proof of Theorem 5.3 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/univid.pdf.